# Get Actual Pixels in android

Tags: android

I am overriding the SurfaceHolder like this and placing an image inside it.

```
public class TestCameraActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
```

I want to get the **x** and **y** position of the this image. How to get it?
Please help.

This is the code:

```
public class TestCameraActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

Camera camera;
SurfaceView surfaceView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
boolean previewing = false;
LayoutInflater controlInflater = null;
ImageView image;
Button b;
View viewControl;
RelativeLayout rel;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);  
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
    viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.control, null);

    image =(ImageView) viewControl.findViewById(R.id.img);

    LayoutParams layoutParamsControl = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);
```

sensorMgr = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        boolean accelSupported = sensorMgr.registerListener(this, SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER, SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
     }

```
@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values) {
        float x = values[0];
        float y = values[1];
        float z = values[2];    
        System.out.println("x = " + x + ", y = " + y + ",z = " + z);

        Rect r = image.getDrawable().getBounds();

        int drawLeft = r.left;
        int drawTop = r.top;
        int drawRight = r.right;
        int drawBottom = r.bottom;

        r.left = (int) x;
        r.right =(int) y;


    }
```

Comment: I want to move the image with the accelerometer. Help please

Comment: Can you please post that class

Comment: Look at my edited answer. Go through the links. It will help you lot. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

As per I understand your question,

You should be able to **get the (x, y) coordinates of the drawable** inside, if that's what you're looking for. Try this:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
Rect r = img.getDrawable().getBounds();

int drawLeft = r.left;
int drawTop = r.top;
int drawRight = r.right;
int drawBottom = r.bottom;
```

**drawLeft** is your X value.

**drawTop** is your Y value.

**EDIT:** Look at this question [Moving an image using Accelerometer of android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457768/moving-an-image-using-accelerometer-of-android) and also this tutorial [Moving Images on the Screen with Android](http://obviam.net/index.php/moving-images-on-the-screen-with-androi/).

Comment: I tried this @Override
 public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values) {
  float x = values[0];
  float y = values[1];
  float z = values[2]; 
  System.out.println("x = " + x + ", y = " + y + ",z = " + z);
 Rect r = image.getDrawable().getBounds();

        int drawLeft = r.left;
        int drawTop = r.top;
        int drawRight = r.right;
        int drawBottom = r.bottom;
        
        r.left = (int) x;
        r.right =(int) y;
        
  
 } but image is not moving. please help. please check my edit