# Animate an image for moving on a particular oval path in android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have an image, which I have already clipped in circle. I want this image to animate over an oval path within angle 20 to 135.

I have searched a lott but i dint get exact answer.

Any help will be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Check out this so - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849554/problem-to-achieve-curved-animation

Answer (score 0):

This animation can be achieved using the Android Accelerometer and the Sensor Manager class.

Refer to this link. It has 3 different detailed sample codes.

[Moving an image using Accelerometer of android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457768/moving-an-image-using-accelerometer-of-android)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://code.google.com/p/android-path-animation/source/browse/src/com/android/example/pathanimation/PathAnimationActivity.java?r=5dc9b17444dc8dd148e532417440ac41168c5aec) out, I was able to move an image on a path.
You can simply define path

```
    AnimatorPath path = new AnimatorPath();
    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, 300);
    path.curveTo(100, 0, 300, 900, 400, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static ObjectAnimator ofObject (Object target, String propertyName, TypeEvaluator evaluator, Object... values)
```

Constructs and returns an ObjectAnimator that animates between Object values. A single value implies that that value is the one being animated to. Two values imply a starting and ending values. More than two values imply a starting value, values to animate through along the way, and an ending value (these values will be distributed evenly across the duration of the animation).

**Parameters**

**target:**     The object whose property is to be animated. This object should have a public method on it called setName(), where name is the value of the propertyName parameter.

**propertyName:**   The name of the property being animated.

**evaluator:**  A TypeEvaluator that will be called on each animation frame to provide the necessary interpolation between the Object values to derive the animated value.

**values:**     A set of values that the animation will animate between over time.

**Returns**
An ObjectAnimator object that is set up to animate between the given values.

For more reference you may check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html#ofObject%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20android.animation.TypeEvaluator,%20java.lang.Object...%29).